# CCK create custom non-standard field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cck

I've created new content type. And I want add new custom non-standard field. The field should consist of two text fields. Let's say: double text field. Ex.: Product content type and I want to add features of product such as: weight, length etc(many features). First field is 'Feature' and the second one is 'Value of feature'. The question is: How I can realize such a field? Module, hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own field pretty easily, you'll need a custom module and to implement a bunch of hooks like you suggest.

Rather than go through all of those here you'd be better off downloading the [Examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples), and looking at `field_example`. I've based tons of custom fields off of that code and they've all worked perfectly. Plus the module is well commented and gives you good insight in to the way the field/widget systems work.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward alternative is to use the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module